# Why Javascript embedded in HTML runs in Internet Explorer 11 but not Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

a newbie question here.  Why does the following code run properly on JSFiddle.net in Internet Explorer 11 but not in Google Chrome?  All I'm trying to do is collect inputs from the user and display them as a list of "Notes" in a table.  I can collect & display w/o issue when using IE11 but in Google Chrome, the Javascript does not even seem to run.

```
<div id="notes">Notes</div>

<script type="text/javascript" onLoad="notes();"> 
// "notes" collects & displays a list of notes as a single-column table

function notes() {
  var notes = [];
  notes[0] = prompt("You can include notes beneath your tasks table. Enter the first one you'd like to include. If you don't want to add any, just hit Enter.");

  var a = 0;

  while (a < 1001 && notes[a] !== 'undefined') {
    notes[a+1] = prompt("Enter the next note. If you don't want to add any more, just hit Enter.");

   a++;
}

  var notesTable = document.createElement("TABLE");

  for (var b = 0; b < notes.length-1; b++) {

    var row = notesTable.insertRow(-1);
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = notes[b];
}

  var notesTableAssign = document.getElementById("notes");
  notesTableAssign.appendChild(notesTable);
  document.getElementByID("notes").appendChild(notesTable);
}

</script>
```

Thank you for any help.

-Justin

Comment: My first guess would be that wiring up your function via a "load" event on the `<script>` tag is the problem. Just add the line `notes();` to the end of the script block and get rid of the "onload".

Comment: Try substituting `document.getElementById("notes")` with lowercase `d` for `document.getElementByID("notes")`

Comment: Both of these answers solved my problem.  I'm now able to run the code in Google Chrome.  Thank you very much.